# How to deal with traffic offences in United Kingdom?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving

I know in the United Kingdom you can fines issued by the Traffic Police Department, for speeding, illegal parking (on public roads) and also you can get fine "Invoices" from private companies that monitor parkings, mostly for example.

What are my rights between the two types of fines?

- As in the appeal processes differences?
- Can i get points on a non uk license?
- Are there limits to fines that are placed by law?
- Is there a cap for the amount of money any of these entities can "claim" for back for this?

Comment: Can you clarify how this is an expat question? Only it feels like [a question that applies equally to locals](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/42/can-questions-that-would-apply-equally-to-locals-be-on-topic)

Comment: Are any of these processes or fines different depending on your status as a resident or system? If not, this is probably something you'll just need to ask the local government.

Comment: I would think these might be actual expat questions: 1. how can they fine you and force you to pay if you are using a non-UK registered car. 2. can they take away my non-UK driving licence in case I make an offence?

Comment: I think that this is relevant to expats as local fines are easy to trip over. Also for expats its easy for them to rack up fines / court if English is not their first langugage.

Comment: IMO the only one expat question that you asked here is *Can i get points on a non uk license?*

Comment: @SztupY In some cases, they could impound your car, and for that the country of registration won't matter!

Comment: @Gagravarr: it matters, as the plate recognition software they are using won't be able to tell them who you are unless they explicitly ask your home country to give some details. This is not UK related, but in Hungary some of the people actually get fines for crimes commited by Belgian drivers, as the registration plate number structure are the same